# Use of <Space> in android layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

What is the use of `<Space />` in andorid ui, how is it any different from an empty linearlayout.

Is there any special use of `<Space>` in android ?

Comment: it is a lighter component. much lighter than a linear layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html):

> Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts.

Yes it is different than a LinearLayout in that it cannot do all (any) of the things that a LinearLayout can do. It's purpose is solely to add a gap between some things. By taking out all of the LinearLayout functionality it makes the view "lighter" which will mean less resource intensive.

Answer (score 2):

`Space` is used to define empty spaces (or gaps) inside a layout.

It was introduced in API level 14 alongside `GridLayout`.

To get a feel of what it's all about, check out this [tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing that tutorial, It was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It’s often possible to take a complicated layout and break it down into a set of nested linear layouts and, provided this nesting doesn’t get too deep, this is still a good choice for many simple layouts.

For use in hierarchies that are too deep and there are performance problems,  is a lightweight View subclass. The keyword being 'lightweight'.